# How to use system functionality programmatically via swift?

Tags: swift, macos, macos-catalina

If we look on hotkeys/shortcuts of the macOS, we can find there a lot of functionality. Some functionality is assigned to hotkeys, some is not.

> As example:
>
> make screenshot(cmd+shif+F5)
>
> or to show desktop (hide all apps) (F11)

and lot of other built-in into the OS functions:

[image]

Question is the following: how to use this functionality from my code without using of hotkeys pressing imitation?

The Goal is do not write custom code in case of such functionality already excist in OS.

---

I have found only how to open some sort of system preferences, maybe this is direction that I need to go, but I didn't found any details via google.

```
import Cocoa

// Open Siri prefs
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Speech.prefPane"))

// Open Siri prefs with another way
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.speech"))

// Open System Preferences window
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference"))
```

Comment: _"...use this functionality..."_, sorry but what functionality are you talking about? Do you mean like taking a screenshot or how to display the desktop from code?

Comment: @Willeke this question is not about screenshot making

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I mean ANY functionality from hotkeys list. First of all I'm interested in "show desktop", but in general I want to have ability to call any of those functions. But without imitation of hotkey press.

Comment: Too broad. The various functionalities have nothing in common, and would be accessed differently if they could be accessed without hot keys at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area you are looking at is System Services, and actually there is no one answer on your question, because some of those items available via own API, some of them are private macOS features, some of them available via actually services.

You can start your findings with:

```
BOOL NSPerformService(NSString *serviceItem, NSPasteboard *pboard)
```

and with [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html), which depicts details of that.

The other mechanism to use those things was AppleScript... very wide area.

Comment: Can you write a sample code for "show desktop" func using `NSPerformService` in your answer? Or func "mission control" ("show all windows") (4 fingers down-to-up movement)